# Haskell Function that Takes A Pair of Values and a List

Tags: list, function, haskell

My homework has been driving me up the wall. I am supposed to write a function called `myRepl` that takes a pair of values and a list and returns a new list such that each occurrence of the first value of the pair in the list is replaced with the second value.

**Example:**

```
ghci> myRepl (2,8) [1,2,3,4] 
> [1,8,3,4].
```

So far I have something like this (but its very rough and not working well at all. I need help with the algorithm:

```
myRep1 (x,y) (z:zs) = 
       if null zs then [] 
       else (if x == z then y : myRep1 zs 
             else myRep1 zs )
```

I don't know how to create a function that takes a pair of values and a list. I'm not sure what the proper syntax is for that, and I'm not sure how to go about the algorithm.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you learned about `map` yet? It would be really helpful to have a function that takes in a pair and a single value and returns the correct value. That might be a stepping stone.

Comment: Well, this cannot work *at all* so far because in the calls to `myRep1` in the function body you are only passing a list, but not a pair.

Comment: It looks like you are on the right track. What isn't working with your current code? Do you get compiler errors? I suspect the answer is yes since you don't pass the pair on to the recursive call.

Comment: how do I even pass a pair through a haskell function?

Comment: @user As an example, the last line of your code could be `else myRep1 (x,y) zs` .

Comment: okay so my code now looks like this `myRep1 (x,y) (z:zs) = if null zs then [] else (if x == z then y : myRep1 zs else myRep1 (x,y) (tail zs))`

Comment: @user Yeah, and it still doesn't even compile for exactly the same reason as before. Make it compile with the info we have given you, then you can tackle the algorithm. Btw, why did you put that `tail` there out of nowhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like:

```
repl (x,y) xs = map (\i -> if i==x then y else i) xs
```

### Explanation

`map` is a function that takes a function, applies it to each value in the list, and combines all the return values of that function into a new list.

The `\i ->` notation is a shortcut for writing the full function definition:

```
-- Look at value i - if it's the same as x, replace it with y, else do nothing
replacerFunc x y i = if x == y then y else i
```

then we can rewrite the `repl` function:

```
repl (x, y) xs = map (replacerFunc x y) xs
```

I'm afraid the `map` function you just have to know - it is relatively easy to see how it works. See the docs:
http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=map

Comment: Well, it is a good idea to explain `map`, but I think it's questionable that you've given the OP a full solution when the first sentence in the question clearly states that this is a homework task.

Comment: Hm... I guess I didn't think of it that way. Is there a policy on this in SO?

Comment: I don't think so, but consider yourself back in college - what if all your course mates had their marked coursework done on SO?

Comment: Not official policy, but community norms: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @us2012 I guess you have a point... On the other hand our profs were really vicious and could find a post like this online easily.

Answer (score 1):

How to write this without `map`? Now, a good rule of thumb is to get the base case of the recursion out of the way first:

```
myRep1 _ [] = ???
```

Now you need a special case if the list element is the one you want to replace. I would recommend a guard for this, as it reads much better than `if`:

```
myRep1 (x,y) (z:zs) 
    | x == z = ???
    | otherwise = ???
```

As this is home work, I left a few blanks for you to fill in :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
myRepl :: Eq a => (a, a) -> [a] -> [a]
myRepl _      []                   = []
myRepl (v, r) (x : xs) | x == v    = r : myRepl (v, r) xs
                       | otherwise = x : myRepl (v, r) xs
```

Untupled arguments, pointfree, in terms of `map`:

```
replaceOccs :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
replaceOccs v r  =  map (\ x -> if x == v then r else x)
```